# Como combinar búsqueda de texto completo con rangos y trigramas en Django 1.10

Tags: django, postgresql, searchview

Estamos usando búsqueda para un proyecto en el que estamos trabajando y necesitamos usar trigramas para hacer las búsquedas.

Este es nuestro código:

```
def get_queryset(self):
        search = self.request.GET.get('text', '')
        vector = SearchVector('name',weight='A',
            config=settings.SEARCH_LANGS[
                settings.LANGUAGE
            ],
            ) + SearchVector(
            'content',
            weight='B',
            config=settings.SEARCH_LANGS[
                settings.LANGUAGE
            ],
            )
        query = SearchQuery(search)
        return Article.objects.annotate(
            rank=SearchRank(
                vector,
                query
                ),
            similarity=TrigramSimilarity(
                'name', search
                ) + TrigramSimilarity(
                'content', search
                ),
            ).filter(
            rank__gte=0.3
            ).filter(
            similarity__gt=0.3
            ).order_by(
            '-similarity'
            )[:20]
```

Pero este código no retorna resultados, cuando no uso trigramas no hay problema, pero combinando tanto rangos como trigramas es que resulta el error.

Como podemos combinar trigramas y pesos en una búsqueda de texto completo en django 1.10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Investigando más a fondo entendimos como funciona la búsqueda de pesos.

Según la [documentación](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/postgres/search/#weighting-queries) se pueden asignar los pesos de acuerdo a los campos y se pueden asignar incluso los pesos, y de igual forma podemos usar trigramas para filtrar por [similaridad](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/postgres/search/#trigram-similarity) o [distancia](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/postgres/search/#trigramdistance).

Sin embargo no especifican un ejemplo de usar los dos e investigando más a fondo tampoco se entiende mucho como funcionan los pesos.

Un poco de lógica nos dice que si buscamos una palabra muy común en todas todos los rangos nos darán 0, similaridad varia mucho más que rangos, sin embargo tiende a dar valores menores que con rango.

Ahora bien, la búsqueda de texto, hasta donde pudimos entender, se lleva a cabo en base al texto contenido en los campos que se quieren filtrar aún más que en el idioma que se coloque en la configuración. Ejemplo de ellos es que al poner títulos, el modelo usado tenía un campo título y un campo contenido, cuyas palabras mas comunes eran 'como cambiar', al revisar los pesos de las palabras (los rangos funcionan como 'query', por lo que podemos usar `values` o `values_list` para revisar los rangos y simularidades, que son valores numéricos, para ver los pesos podemos revisar el objecto vector), vimos que si se asignaban pesos `A`, pero a combinaciones de palabras 'recortadas': encontramos 'perfil' y también 'cambi', sin embargo no encontramos 'cambiar' o 'como'; sim embargo, todos los modelos tenían como contenido el mismo texto 'lorem ipsun...', y todas las palabras de esa frase si estaban integras y con pesos `B`; deducimos con esto que la búsquedas se hacen en base al contenido de los campos a filtrar más que el idioma con el que configuramos las búsquedas.

Este es el resultado del ejemplo dado anteriormente en cuanto a pesos se refieren:

```
In [21]: query_set.values('vector')
Out[21]: <QuerySet [{'vector': "'accusamus':32B 'accusantium':21B 'adipisicing':13B 'amet':11B 'beata':15B 'cambi':2A 'consectetur':12B 'consequatur':29B 'contraseñ':4A 'delectus':36B 'dolor':9B,31B 'dolorum':24B 'earum':18B 'elit':14B 'excepturi':20B 'incidunt':17B 'ipsum':8B 'laborum':25B 'lorem':7B 'minus':22B 'natus':27B 'null':23B 'pariatur':19B 'perfil':6A 'provident':30B 'quam':26B 'quas':35B 'quibusdam':16B 'quos':28B 'repellendus':34B 'reprehenderit':33B 'sit':10B"}, {'vector': "'accusamus':31B 'accusantium':20B 'adipisicing':12B 'amet':10B 'beata':14B 'cambi':2A 'consectetur':11B 'consequatur':28B 'corre':4A 'delectus':35B 'dolor':8B,30B 'dolorum':23B 'earum':17B 'electron':5A 'elit':13B 'excepturi':19B 'incidunt':16B 'ipsum':7B 'laborum':24B 'lorem':6B 'minus':21B 'natus':26B 'null':22B 'pariatur':18B 'provident':29B 'quam':25B 'quas':34B 'quibusdam':15B 'quos':27B 'repellendus':33B 'reprehenderit':32B 'sit':9B"}, {'vector': "'accusamus':34B 'accusantium':23B 'adipisicing':15B 'amet':13B 'beata':17B 'cambi':2A 'consectetur':14B 'consequatur':31B 'delectus':38B 'dolor':11B,33B 'dolorum':26B 'earum':20B 'elit':16B 'excepturi':22B 'fot':4A 'incidunt':19B 'ipsum':10B 'laborum':27B 'lorem':9B 'minus':24B 'natus':29B 'null':25B 'pariatur':21B 'perfil':6A 'provident':32B 'quam':28B 'quas':37B 'quibusdam':18B 'quos':30B 'repellendus':36B 'reprehenderit':35B 'sit':12B 'usuari':8A"}, {'vector': "'accusamus':32B 'accusantium':21B 'adipisicing':13B 'amet':11B 'beata':15B 'cambi':2A 'consectetur':12B 'consequatur':29B 'delectus':36B 'dolor':9B,31B 'dolorum':24B 'earum':18B 'elit':14B 'excepturi':20B 'incidunt':17B 'ipsum':8B 'laborum':25B 'lorem':7B 'minus':22B 'natus':27B 'nombr':4A 'null':23B 'pariatur':19B 'provident':30B 'quam':26B 'quas':35B 'quibusdam':16B 'quos':28B 'repellendus':34B 'reprehenderit':33B 'sit':10B 'usuari':6A"}, {'vector': "'accusamus':31B 'accusantium':20B 'adipisicing':12B 'amet':10B 'beata':14B 'cambi':2A 'consectetur':11B 'consequatur':28B 'dat':4A 'delectus':35B 'dolor':8B,30B 'dolorum':23B 'earum':17B 'elit':13B 'excepturi':19B 'incidunt':16B 'ipsum':7B 'laborum':24B 'lorem':6B 'minus':21B 'natus':26B 'null':22B 'pariatur':18B 'personal':5A 'provident':29B 'quam':25B 'quas':34B 'quibusdam':15B 'quos':27B 'repellendus':33B 'reprehenderit':32B 'sit':9B"}, {'vector': "'accusamus':32B 'accusantium':21B 'adipisicing':13B 'alta':4A 'amet':11B 'beata':15B 'consectetur':12B 'consequatur':29B 'darm':2A 'delectus':36B 'dolor':9B,31B 'dolorum':24B 'earum':18B 'elit':14B 'excepturi':20B 'incidunt':17B 'ipsum':8B 'laborum':25B 'lorem':7B 'minus':22B 'natus':27B 'null':23B 'pariatur':19B 'provident':30B 'quam':26B 'quas':35B 'quibusdam':16B 'quos':28B 'repellendus':34B 'reprehenderit':33B 'sit':10B 'siti':6A"}, {'vector': "'accusamus':30B 'accusantium':19B 'adipisicing':11B 'amet':9B 'beata':13B 'bootcamp':4A 'consectetur':10B 'consequatur':27B 'delectus':34B 'dolor':7B,29B 'dolorum':22B 'earum':16B 'elit':12B 'excepturi':18B 'formul':2A 'incidunt':15B 'ipsum':6B 'laborum':23B 'lorem':5B 'minus':20B 'natus':25B 'null':21B 'pariatur':17B 'provident':28B 'quam':24B 'quas':33B 'quibusdam':14B 'quos':26B 'repellendus':32B 'reprehenderit':31B 'sit':8B"}, {'vector': "'accusamus':30B 'accusantium':19B 'adipisicing':11B 'amet':9B 'beata':13B 'consectetur':10B 'consequatur':27B 'delectus':34B 'dolor':7B,29B 'dolorum':22B 'earum':16B 'elit':12B 'emprend':4A 'excepturi':18B 'incidunt':15B 'inici':2A 'ipsum':6B 'laborum':23B 'lorem':5B 'minus':20B 'natus':25B 'null':21B 'pariatur':17B 'provident':28B 'quam':24B 'quas':33B 'quibusdam':14B 'quos':26B 'repellendus':32B 'reprehenderit':31B 'sit':8B"}, {'vector': "'/uploads/markdownx/528beb34-2d83-41ee-ae54-92b1f9c8df81.gif':6B 'hac':3A 'pendej':5A 'pregunt':4A"}]>
```

A simple vista podemos ver que ha tomado todas las palabras como si de idioma latín se tratara, por más que en la configuración hallamos dicho que el idioma es español, por lo que si vamos a buscar todas las palabras con peso `A` vemos que no encontramos las palabras `como`, o `cambiar`, pero si encontramos `cambi`y otras que no tienen nada que ver con español, como excepción encontramos `perfil`.

Dicho esto, exponemos acá el código que usamos para todo.

Primeramente, para usar Trigramas necesitamos habilitar la [extensión](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/postgres/search/#trigram-similarity) necesaria en la base de datos:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion
from django.contrib.postgres.operations import UnaccentExtension
from django.contrib.postgres.operations import TrigramExtension

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
    ]

    operations = [
      ...
      TrigramExtension(),
      UnaccentExtension(),

    ]
```

Importamos del paquete de `postgres` las operaciones para migraciones y las ejecutamos desde cualquier archivo de migración.

El siguiente paso es cambiar el código de la pregunta de manera que al filtrar retorne uno de los querys si falla el segundo:

```
def get_queryset(self):
        search_query = SearchQuery(self.request.GET.get('q', ''))

        vector = SearchVector(
            'name',
            weight='A',
            config=settings.SEARCH_LANGS[settings.LANGUAGE_CODE],
        ) + SearchVector(
            'content',
            weight='B',
            config=settings.SEARCH_LANGS[settings.LANGUAGE_CODE],
        )

        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            queryset = Article.actives.all()
        else:
            queryset = Article.publics.all()

        return queryset.annotate(
          rank=SearchRank(vector, search_query)
          similarity=TrigramSimilarity(
              'name', search
            ) + TrigramSimilarity(
              'content', search
            ),
        ).filter(Q(rank__gte=0.3) | Q(similarity__gt=0.3)).order_by('-rank')[:20]
```

El problema con el anterior código era que filtraba un query después del otro, y en caso de que la palabra escogida no aparezca en alguna de las dos búsquedas el problema es mayor. Usamos un objeto `Q` para poder filtrar usando un conector `OR`de forma que si uno de los dos no retorna un valor deseado, envíe al otro en su lugar.

Con esto es suficiente, sin embargo son bienvenidas las aclaraciones a profundidad sobre como funcionan estos pesos y trigramas, para poder explitar la máximo esta nueva ventaja que nos ofrece la última versión de Django.

Comment: Agradecería mucho que me dejaran sus comentarios y anotaciones, para  corregir y añadir cosas útiles y que el esfuerzo valga la pena. Gracias :D